# Save user's last log out

Tags: yii

I am trying to save user's last logout time into a DB in Yii framework.
I have WebUser as:

```
<?php

// this file must be stored in:
// protected/components/WebUser.php

class WebUser extends CWebUser {



    public function afterLogout()

    {
        $user=user::Model();
        $user->logOutDateTime='TEST';
        $user->saveAttributes(array('logOutDateTime'));
        parent::afterLogout();  
    }

}
?>
```

and in config\main.php I have these lines

```
// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
            'class'=>'WebUser',
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,

    )
```

For now I have set logOutDateTime datatype to varchar, to test, and I assume every time user logs out, it should write `'TEST'` into database but it does nothing.
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the afterLogout() still has the Yii::app()->user set, so I would do something like (untested):

```
public function beforeLogout()
{
    if (parent::beforeLogout()) {
        $user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id); // assuming you have getId() mapped to id column
        $user->logOutDateTime='TEST';
        $user->saveAttributes(array('logOutDateTime'));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = user::Model();
```

should be:

```
$user = user::Model()->find(/* model_conditions */);
```